# i have a problem in flutter i dont have any idea i try all methods

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sdk, virtual, statelesswidget

[vs wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeuDX.png)

[android studio wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3mT1.png)

[it is my first wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9T6S.png)

i installed flutter but i am getting errors like this i got my error about java installed sdk installed sdk i have no idea i am waiting for your help
virtual studio code say Exception: Build process failed.

Comment: install flutter plugin to your sdk. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter#:~:text=This%20VS%20Code%20extension%20adds,menu%20for%20full%20debugging%20functionality.

Comment: What is your java version that you installed? 
and run flutter doctor command then write the result here
and did you installed flutter plugin?

Comment: Have you imported material.dart File ?  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Comment: I downloaded flutter plugin but it doesn't work flutter plugin with dart

Comment: @MohamedReda 
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1586], locale tr-TR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
• No issues found!  java version openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20  i install plugins

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem you have

> java version openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20

and you mustn't have any Java JDK version after Java 8, to explain why, all you need to know is that Google doesn't support any java version after 8 it's because that Google had a lawsuit with oracle (who support Java) for not fitting the standards with the new versions of Java, that is why google is trying to replase it with Kotlin, so:

1. uninstall java and
2. install Java 8 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html)

If it still not working, get me the error and will update the answer, but now we solved the Java problem.

Comment: same wrong Exception: Build process failed.

Comment: okey, maybe it's another problem, so keep Java 8, can you create a new Flutter project, if it still not working, get the error massage here because all of it is not visible at the images?